# Preserve formatting while copying the content of a table cell in a word and pasting it in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell in a table with mix of strike through words and plain words (without strike through). I was able to extract those value from the table cell of a word document and put it in a excel document. However, when i put it in a cell in an excel document, it pasted as plain words alone without strike through effects. So, can you suggest some way to retain the strike through effect while putting it in an excel please? Below is the snippet of my code.

```
Range("I54") = ObjDoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2)  --> This extract the values without strike through effect.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but in VBA word if you do:

```
MsgBox (Selection.Font.StrikeThrough)
```

You will get `-1` if striketrough effect is on, and `0` if not.

In Excel VBA, If you do something like:

```
msgbox (Range("I54").Font.Strikethrough)
```

It will return `True/False` depending if striketrough effect is applied to cell or not.

As far as I know, `True=-1` so maybe your code will work if you do it like this:

```
Range("I54") = ObjDoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2)
Range("I54").Font.Strikethrough = ObjDoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Font.Strikethrough
```

But not tested. Probably you can do it in 2 steps like above.